Old martial arts movie with Bruce Lee and Japanese antagonist?
I remember watching (many years ago, I was a kid) a movie with Bruce Lee as a protagonist.
An important plot point was that one of the other characters, if I remember correctly, outed himself as Japanese by removing his own shirt and exposing Japanese-looking nipples, or at least that's what I understood at that time.
Do you have any idea of which movie I'm talking about? I've had no luck finding the title with Google.

"I've had no luck finding the title with Google" -> a simple google search with the words "bruce lee movie with japanese" gives "Fist of fury" as its 1st result...

This is the 1972 Bruce Lee film Fist of Fury, which prominently features several Japanese characters as antagonists.
At one point, Lee's character Chen realises that a character is a Japanese spy, not because he has "Japanese-looking nipples", but because the sarashi wrap he's wearing under his shirt exposes his nipples, whereas a Chinese man would cover his nipples with his sarashi. I can imagine this cultural detail being lost in translation if you're not Chinese or Japanese.
Sadly, I can't find a clip of it, but TV Tropes corroborates that particular plot detail (obligatory warning: massive time sink!):

Sarashi: In some edits, Chen is able to figure out someone is a Japanese spy when he spots them in a sarashi. Not so much by what he's wearing but in how he's wearing it. The man's nipples were exposed, as is standard for Japanese men (as in the page image); Chinese prefer to keep them hidden


Thank you very much, I'm a bit glad that it was at least nipple (nippon) related
